# Optaplanner: The selectionList contains 2 times the same selection (lack of null ids)

Tags: optaplanner

I know that this question has been asked before and the comment contains that the solution was the lack of null ids, but I have the same problem and I can't understand the comment which is used to solve the problem.

what is the meaning of "lack of null ids" and how I overcome this problem?

Comment: Wasn't this because some of the `...examples.AbstractPersistable.id` in a copy paste from the examples where `null` in a specific dataset?

Comment: I can't understand your question, would you please try to clarify more for me?

Comment: I make the system print the ids given to each element in the input data and all of them were given a unique id.

Comment: Then that's not it. In that case, the question is unclear to me.